# Problemas ao fazer echo de um Notebook Textarea

Tags: php

Criei um `Notebook Textarea` para registar informações importantes do dia. Ao fazer echo dentro do `Notebook Textarea` cria um diferente para cada linha inserida na tabela da base de dados, como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o que pretendo é que retorne as linhas da base de dados mas sempre dentro do mesmo `Notebook Textarea`.

Código:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM raddb.Informacao WHERE DATE(data) = CURDATE() ORDER BY data Desc";

$result = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error);

<div class="table-responsive">
<form id="paper" method="post" action="">
<div class="form-group input-group input-group-lg">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></span>
Informações do Dia</span>
</div>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{
?>
<textarea id="text" name="text" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 160px;" readonly="true"><?php echo $row["text"]; ?></textarea> 
<?php
}
?>    
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PHP_EOL` (à partir do PHP 5.0.2) para quebrar as linhas, mas faça o laço dentro do `textarea` para não repeti-lo:

```
<textarea id="text" name="text" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 160px;" readonly="true">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row["text"].PHP_EOL;
}
?>    
</textarea>
```